# add prototype to object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a base function which i want to inherit from:

```
function Base() {
    this._dummy = 1;
};
Base.prototype.notify = function () {
    alert("Notify");
};
```

Creating another constructor class works:

```
function Concrete1() {};
Concrete1.prototype = new Base();
var concr1 = new Concrete1();
concr1.notify(); // alerts "Notify"
```

Declaring an object like this doesn't work, probably because the object doesn't have a prototype

```
var concrete2 = new function () {};
concrete2.prototype = new Base();
concrete2.notify(); // doesn't work
```

I don't want to create `Concrete2` constructor because it will only be one instance of it.

Can i make "inheritance" work with `new function()` method?

Comment: Typo mistake, sorry. is `concrete2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Base` is a constructor function, if you want a single object that uses `Base.prototype` as its base, as [Brian Peacock points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779388/157247) you can just use the constructor:

```
var concrete2 = new Base();
concrete2.notify(); // Works
```

If you want to add further features to the `concrete2` instance, you can do that directly:

```
concrete2.doSomethingElse = function() { /* ... */ };
```

That works because you already have a constructor function, so the simplest way to create a single object backed by that constructor's prototype is to use the `new` operator.

Sometimes, though, you want to use an object when either it's not associated with a constructor function, or you have a reason for not wanting to call that constructor function. In those situations (I'll give an example of one below), you can use `Object.create`, which is in ES5 and which can be partially shimmed in older browsers:

```
// Creates an object backed by Base.prototype without calling Base
var concrete2 = Object.create(Base.prototype);
concrete2.notify(); // Works
```

`Object.create` creates a new object directly, setting its prototype to the object you pass into it. The single-argument version of it can be shimmed on older browsers, which is also useful for knowing what it does:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "The two-argument version of Object.create cannot be shimmed.";
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor();
    };
}
```

One use of this is exemplified by flagging up an issue with some of the other code in the question, which uses a common, but not ideal, means of setting up inheritance between `Concrete1` and `Base`. This is the problematic line:

```
Concrete1.prototype = new Base();                    // Not ideal
```

The issue is: What if `Base` does something that should only be instance-specific? For instance, suppose it accepts instance-specific arguments? (Which is one, but only one, way `Base` could have instance-specific code in it.) Calling `Base` is almost never the correct way to set up the prototype for a "subclass" of it. Instead, you use `Object.create`:

```
Concrete1.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype); // Better
```

...usually followed by:

```
Concrete1.prototype.constructor = Concrete1;
```

...just because that's how the spec defines the prototype property of function instances (it says `constructor` will be the function, but then never actually uses `constructor` for anything).

Then you call `Base` from the `Concrete1` function when its creating an actual instance:

```
function Concrete1(any, necessary, args) {
    Base.call(this, any, necessary); // For example
    this.args = args;                // For example
}
```

Complete example:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;
}
Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
/* ...further Person-specific functions put on Person.prototype here...*/

function Employee(firstName, lastName, jobTitle) {
    Person.call(this, firstName, lastName);
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
}
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
/* ...Employee-specific functions put on Employee.prototype here...*/

function Manager(firstName, lastName, jobTitle) {
    Employee.call(this, firstName, lastName);
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
/* ...Manager-specific functions put on Manager.prototype here...*/
```

...and so on. (Or use a helper script like my [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) script, which also helps with supercalls and simplifies things a fair bit.)

Comment: Looks interesting! i will have to play with them to understand how they work like this

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains two small errors:

1. When defining `concrete1` you do not need the `new` keyword in front of the function.
2. The way you called `concrete2.notify()` will not work because you don't have an instance of the new class.  `concrete2.prototype.notify()` will work, as will `new concrete2().notify()`.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eeLh/1/) for a working version (with some renaming for clarity).

**Edit/Rewrite**:

Thank you to @T.J.Crowder for pointing out that @RaraituL was looking for a singleton that inherits the base class.

In most cases you could simply create an instance of `Base` and modify it's the properties that you wish to add/overwrite. While this will not provide prototypical inheritance, it will likely achieve the desired result:

```
function Base() {
    this._dummy = 1;
};

Base.prototype.notify = function () {
    alert("Notify");
};

Concrete1 = new Base();

//My Extension of Base
Concrete1.foo = function() {
    //Some method
}
```

This solution could break down if you have code that expects a "clean" prototype chain structure in order to reference parent classes. However, that is not a normal use case and would likely be very unclear code as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good point, I suppose I was in debug mode when writing the answer. I'm checking out this `Object.create` business and it looks like an interesting solution.